# How do I prevent the standard Bitcoin client from sending some of my Bitcoins to a change address?

Tags: address, paper-wallet, coldstorage, change

I found somebody that imported a paper wallet with 100BTC then used 2BTC BUT the other 98BTC were sent to a change address. Why and how can I prevent this; how can I enter a custom change address?

Comment: Where DO you want the change to go, if not to a change address? Back to the same address? You could make the raw transaction yourself, telling where to send each of the outputs. That might be a little too technical for what you're looking for, possibly. If not, I can post an answer detailing how one would do that.

Comment: Obviously I don't mean like making the transaction byte by byte, by hand. I mean you can use the RPC commands and manually say where you want all the coins to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard client doesn't have any built-in options for this. You could manage it yourself if you built the transaction by the [RPC API commands](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) or, more easily, by using a client with that feature built in, like [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/):

[image: Armory change selection feature]

Or, if you know what inputs will be used and the exact amounts involved, you can add the "change" yourself as an additional output. This will make it so the client won't need to generate any additional change back to itself. Remember to subtract a transaction fee, if necessary.

[image: Bitcoin Core, preparing to send 2 BTC to one address and the other 100 BTC to another]

Comment: How do I do in blockchain?

Comment: @Tor Are you referring to blockchain.info?

Comment: Blockchain.info's wallet has a feature a little like Armory: you can choose where the change goes, as long as it's an address already in your wallet (Armory lets you send it anywhere).

Comment: @NickODell plz... I want help not money...

Comment: How do I report comments...

Comment: @Tor when you hover over a comment, there's a "flag" icon in the lower left corner. For the record, I don't see anything wrong with any (existing) comments by NickODell: just one asking if by "blockchain" you mean "blockchain.info", which is a perfectly reasonable and polite clarification question: in short, a perfect comment.